# Defining the elements of a list of list as new variables in common lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I have a list of lists as follows in Common Lisp of the form

```
((1 2) (3 4) (5 6))
```

and which is the value of the variable `list`, and I want to have three new variables whose values are the elements of the list.  For instance:

```
list-1 (1 2)
list-2 (3 4)
list-3 (5 6)
```

Is there any function which does this operation?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`setq`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/s_setq.htm), [`first`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_firstc.htm) (or [`nth`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_nth.htm) and [`elt`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_elt.htm)) to *set*:

```
(setq list-1 (first list)
      list-2 (second list)
      list-3 (third list))
```

Or [`destructuring-bind`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_destru.htm) to *bind*:

```
(destructuring-bind (list-1 list-2 list-3) list
  ...)
```

Again, `destructuring-bind` [**binds**](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/26_glo_b.htm#binding) the variables instead of [**assigning**](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/26_glo_a.htm#assign) them (i.e., it is like [`let`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/s_let_l.htm), not like [`setq`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/s_setq.htm)).

Comment: Also, instead of `first`, `second`, etc., you can use `nth`: `(nth 0 list)` returns `'(1 2)` .

Answer (score 2):

The notion of binding elements of a list to names of the form `list-#` can be generalized.

You can create a function to generate a lambda with the ordinal list names as arguments, and a given body:

```
(defun make-list-lambda (n body)
  (let ((list-names (loop for index from 1 to n
     collect (intern (format nil "LIST-~D" index)))))
    `(lambda ,list-names
       (declare (ignorable ,@list-names))
       ,@body)))
```

And then create a macro to create the lambda, compile it, and apply it to the list:

```
(defmacro letlist (list &body body)
  (let ((assignments (gensym)))
    `(let ((,assignments ,list))
       (apply (compile nil (make-list-lambda (length ,assignments) ',body))
          ,assignments))))
```

In this way, the assignments are localized to the lambda body:

```
CL-USER> (letlist '(a b c d e f)
       (format t "list-1: ~A~%" list-1)
       (format t "list-3: ~A~%" list-3))
list-1: A
list-3: C
NIL
```

**Note:** The forms will be compiled every time the macro is invoked, since it will not be known how many `list-#` arguments will be present until the list is presented!

Answer (score -1):

First set your list to a variable, for instance mylist. Then spit out the required
output using the function format. I'm using CLISP. Hope this helps. This is the actual REPL output.

`(setf mylist '((1 2) (3 4) (5 6)) )`

((1 2) (3 4) (5 6))

`(format t "list-1 ~d~%list-2 ~d~%list-3 ~d" (car mylist)` 
                (second mylist) (last mylist))
list-1 (1 2)
list-2 (3 4)
list-3 ((5 6))
NIL
[142]>
Can someone show me how to get rid of "NIL' in the above output?
I'm new to Lisp. Just learning for fun.